Can a Catholic sign the 1974 evangelical Lausanne Covenant?
I came across a recent Christianity Today article highlighting the importance of the forgotten 1974 Lausanne Covenant for the unity of the many factions of evangelicalism WITHOUT requiring doctrinal uniformity.  For example, no agreement on Baptism or on the issue of female minister is needed for its signatories.
My question: Is there anything in the covenant that contradict a Catholic doctrine, or is it mainstream enough that a Catholic can sign it?

From a RC perspective you should not just ask the question if anything in the document is contradicting Catholic faith. Acts and signs have meaning for catholics as well. So you should ask if the signing of this document in itself is fitting for a catholic. Would you sign a document for the unity of, let's say, Muslim factions, even if you find nothing contradicting your faith in it?

@ABMK Among competing Protestant denominations, as I explicitly mentioned in my question, they do NOT see it as doctrinal uniformity.  The signing is like an agreement for joint action in the world, similar like participating in a Billy Graham crusade.  The signing is affirming common grounds of all Christians for joint efforts such as to bring justice to the downtrodden (Chapter 5) and love of Christ (chapter 3) to the world.  In this spirit, I think this is comparable to Pope JP II visiting a mosque and a synagogue.  Of course by doing that the Pope did NOT contradict the Catholic faith?

I just think one should ask the question what signals you give. And I am not commenting on the holy pope.

I was reading through the document and I already see issues for Catholic/Orthodox churches in section 2.

§2 "... the only infallible rule of faith and practice"

This in not accepted by Catholics/Orthodox who believe that there is another aspect of infallible rule (Pope // Full body of the church)

§6 "... The church is the community of God’s people rather than an institution, and must not be identified with any particular culture, social or political system, or human ideology."

I'm not sure the Catholics/Orthodox would agree here with that ending. Yes the church is of God, but it is in the world. Certainly the Greek orthodox, Russian orthodox, and High bishop of ROME might have something to do with a particular culture or ideology.

The later sections seem to focus on confirming the urgency of the need to go out and do missionary work, in the usual manner that Protestants seem to prefer. I can only speak for the Orthodox side of this, our method is "come and see" and not "go out and convince"


§14 I think something is wrong with what they said about the Holy Spirit here, my answer is incomplete here. It feels off somehow.


§14 "A church that is not a missionary church is contradicting itself and quenching the Spirit. "

Catholics and Orthodox will disagree, a church does not need to be a missionary church to be filled with God. Many churches are missionary, some exist to maintain the average person, some exist to be bastions of the faith, and certainly there are monasteries/abbeys (which are churches as well!) that are focused inwards. This does not mean that the Holy Spirit is being "quenched!"

I believe the answer to your question is objectively no due to §2 and §14 being incompatible with the Catholic (and Orthodox) church.
